# Who were the nine founding railroad members of the Chicago union stock yard?

Tags: 19th-century, railroads, chicago

All nine of the founding railroad companies of the Chicago stock yard. All presidents of the founding members during this time (1864)

Comment: Some question marks would be useful, just so we're sure what you're asking. Thanks.

Comment: Recommend closure until this is updated to both ask a question and document preliminary research. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_Stock_Yards) seems to list most of the founding members), the text seems to be plagiarized from/by [source](https://drloihjournal.blogspot.com/2018/08/history-of-the-union-stock-yards-and-transit-company-chicago-1865-1971.html)

Comment: Is there a rule about downvoting brand new members on their first question? I fear it may be off-putting to them, causing them to abandon the site. Has this been discussed before? What's the proper place to bring that up?

Comment: @JimmyG. Look on [History meta](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=new+users).

Comment: @JimmyG. - Very good point and I'm glad you raised it - I'll try to be more aware in the future. That said, SE assumes that new users do a bit of research before they ask - check to see what other questions look like, reach the "What questions are welcome here?" section, etc.  In our case we expect (a) a question, (b) preliminary research. Prior to the edit, it wasn't clear that this was a question or what OP wanted to know.    All that said, SE has  floated the idea of marking first questions in some way, and in this case I wish that were possible. I would have responded differently.

Answer (score 2):

(partial answer)

The railroads are detailed [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Food_Investigation/ekQMAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA194&printsec=frontcover) (reformatted into more readable list form)

> The plan was made possible through an agreement reached by nine
> railroads handling shipments of live stock to and from Chicago by
> which it was agreed that they would give up the yards they were then
> maintaining in widely separated sections of the city and that in the
> future such live stock business would be handled through the Union
> Stock Yard & Transit Co These nine railroads were as follows
>
> 1. The Pittsburgh Fort Wayne & Chicago Railway Co
> 2. the Michigan Southern & Northern Indiana Railroad Co
> 3. the Michigan Central Railroad Co
> 4. the Chicago & Great Eastern Railroad Co
> 5. the Chicago Burlington & Quincy Railroad Co
> 6. the Chicago & North Western Railway Co
> 7. the Chicago Rock Island & Pacific Railroad Co
> 8. the Chicago & Alton Railroad Co and
> 9. the Illinois Central Railroad Co